# Triggers: Adjacency List to a Nested Set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, nested-sets, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency list on a legacy system that I would like to query recursively (need to get subtotals, etc).

Can I make a trigger in MySQL that either store in a separate table, or alternatively store in separate columns in the same table the "Nested Set Equivalent" of a given set?

My set is like this:

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|          id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

I want this:

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
|          id | name                 | lft | rgt |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   1 |  20 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: have you done it yourself maybe? I'd need it as well... :)

Comment: unfortunately no :(

I ended up doing a (kindof messy and less than ideal) application side solution using recursion.. I have found some resources though that may help:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html

I think this is based off of Joe Celko's work. If you do end up finding a way to do this with triggers, please post it!